# Changing a table up in c#/asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a chart showing, and of course the data that was bound to it, but I need to display it differently..

This is how I have the table now:

[image: first table]

and this is how I need it:

[image: second table]

But without hardcoding most of it I can't think of how to get it from the first to the second, any ideas? :/

Extra explanation if it wasn't clear:
I need the first column to become just one row for each region, then all the possible test statuses to become a column, with the test count being displayed for each region/test, grand total isn't that important

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? If you're using T-SQL I'd do a pivot and create a temp table to retrieve the pivoted information from. You'd have to do some other grouping and such, but this could at least give you a head start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show there is know as a cross-tab, matrix, or most commonly a pivot table, because you are pivoting a column of values into headers.

This can be accomplished many ways.

- Using an OLAP or analytical engine.
- Using something like Excel to create a pivot table.
- Using a reporting engine that supports pivots.
- Using a pivot or OLAP framework component(there are many that vary from database oriented, to simply in memory manipulation, to client side visual controls)
- Using an SQL PIVOT query

You'll need to evaluate your architecture and user requirements to determine what combination best fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks! At the very least you gave me the name of what I was looking for so I should be good from here :)